# Why cant I remove the backround-attachment: fixed property from the header at a max-width of 1024px

Tags: html, css

So at a max-width of 1024px I wanna remove the backround-attachment: fixed property from the header's background image. backround-attachment: null and backround-attachment: none aren't working at all? any Ideas?? Also the js posted below is irrelevant it's only there so I can post this fiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/3v1wsm5n/3/

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.nav-box');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('#menu-close');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('#left');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('#right');
const img = document.querySelector('.image-slider');
let num = 1;


ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.add('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '50px';
})

menuClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.remove('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '-700px';
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
 num--;
 if(num > 0) {
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
  console.log(num);
  console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
 } else {
  num = 4;
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
 }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
 num++;
 if(num <= 4) {
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
  console.log(num);
  console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
 } else {
  num = 1;
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
 } 
})

// window.sr = ScrollReveal();

// sr.reveal('.logo-wrap', {
//  duration: 2000
// });

// sr.reveal('.w1', {
//  duration: 2000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.w2', {
//  duration: 3000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.w3', {
//  duration: 4000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hours-line-left', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'left',
//  distance: '200px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hours-line-right', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '200px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.contact-line', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.burrito', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.taco', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.guac', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.nachos', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hot', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'left',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.back-to-top', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
// });

// sr.reveal('.btp-arrow', {
//  duration: 1500,
//  origin: 'top',
//  distance: '250px'
// });
```

Comment: Try `background-attachment: initial;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typically a good idea to look at the available [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp) to see what properties are allowed. CSS isn't a programing language so values like `null` aren't supported the way you expect.

Instead, you often need to set the value back to "browsers default" instead of "none" by using the `initial` property.

So in your case `background-attachment: initial` would set that property back to the browser's default of `scroll` (meaning it moves with the page).